# BasicTabbedPaneUI showing border when focused

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to make a custom TabbedPaneUI by extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI`

I am having an issue with setting the TextColor, When ever I set the TextColor it shows a border when the pane is focused and enabled.

[image]

as you can see the pane that has the title `Test` is enabled/selected Pane and it has a white border around it and I do not want the border. I have already overrided `paintTabBorder`

```
@Override
protected void paintTabBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
    //We do nothing here to disable painting the Tab Border
}
```

here is how I am overriding `paintText` to change the Text Color

```
@Override
protected void paintText(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Font font, FontMetrics metrics, int tabIndex, String title, Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {

    g.setFont(font);

    View v = getTextViewForTab(tabIndex);
    if (v != null) {
        // html
        v.paint(g, textRect);
    } else {
        // plain text
        int mnemIndex = tabPane.getDisplayedMnemonicIndexAt(tabIndex);

        if (tabPane.isEnabled() && tabPane.isEnabledAt(tabIndex)) {

            //Change the text to White here <- Causing Border Issues
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());

        } else { // tab disabled
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).brighter());
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).darker());
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x - 1, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent() - 1);

        }
    }
}
```

`g.setColor(Color.WHITE);` is causing the border issue, I have confirmed this by setting the Color to something else rather then White and the border was also that color aswell as the Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I have figured out how to fix the border issue I had to set the graphics color after drawing the String. `g.setColor(selectColor);`

```
            //Change the text to White here <- Causing Border Issues
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());

            //reset the color to selectedColor
            g.setColor(selectColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just draw another empty title with the background color to effectively hide the border.

```
@Override
protected void paintText(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Font font, FontMetrics metrics, int tabIndex, String title, Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {

    g.setFont(font);

    View v = getTextViewForTab(tabIndex);
    if (v != null) {
        // html
        v.paint(g, textRect);
    } else {
        // plain text
        int mnemIndex = tabPane.getDisplayedMnemonicIndexAt(tabIndex);

        if (tabPane.isEnabled() && tabPane.isEnabledAt(tabIndex)) {

            //Change the text to White here
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());

            //Remove Border Issues
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).darker());

            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    "", mnemIndex,                                 //<-- empty title here
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());

        } else { // tab disabled
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).brighter());
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).darker());
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x - 1, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent() - 1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not fix the border issue, It just changes the border color to blueish color. http://prntscr.com/lijg5u